# Crash in go program doing a lot of I/O

Tags: go

I am trying to write to 100000 files in parallel with Go.

I am not sure why, but this code below crashes ~30% of the time when I call it with the argv parameter "100000".

Here is the crash:

```
goroutine 3749 [chan send]:
main.CallShellCommand(0xc820016180, 0xea1)
        .../parallel.go:13 +0x1bf
created by main.main
        .../parallel.go:22 +0xbd
```

Here is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "io/ioutil"
import "strconv"
import "os"
import "runtime"

func CallCommand(ch chan struct{}, id int) {
    ioutil.WriteFile(fmt.Sprintf("/tmp/my_prefix_%d", id), []byte("HELLO\n"), 0644)
    ch <- struct{}{}
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4)
    n, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[1])
    ch := make(chan struct{})
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        go CallCommand(ch, i+1)
    }
    for j := 0; j < n; j++ {
        <-ch
    }
}
```

For the record:

- My computer has 4 cores
- This is go 1.5.3

Comment: You ignore errors: `ioutil.WriteFile()`. DON'T ignor errors.

Comment: I let it as is for simplicity sake, to make the minimum example crashing, In the read code, I am handling error and it does not help, the program is still crashing.

Comment: That's what you say! I get `open /tmp/so/my_prefix_26135: too many open files`. And `open /tmp/so/my_prefix_38352: too many open files` 
`open /tmp/so/my_prefix_38698: too many open files`, And so on.

Comment: Writing 10000 files in parallel is not an efficient way to do IO. Not to mention, each of those Writes will consume a full OS threads, so you need to have the resources to handle the pthread stack of each, along with other suitably set resources limits.

Comment: I check for errors; you don't. I have reproducible errors; you don't. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can anyone explain how writing 100000 files in parallel can help with hardware IOPS limits? I'm not sure but for me it looks like it will increase overall write time.

Comment: If you really *need* to do 100k parallel writes to files, you might consider using the [`poller` package](https://godoc.org/github.com/npat-efault/poller) which uses async kernel I/O. Note that the limits mentioned by @PeterSO will still apply but you'll end up with occupying just a single OS thread with your write (or none at all). To make my suggestion more clear: by using async I/O you'll multiplex your writes over whatever throughput your kernel will realistically provide given the target media and workload.

Comment: I also wonder why the error message cites `CallShellCommand` (notice "Shell"). So we might be dealing with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here, to begin with.

Comment: I will close the question, I managed to get the error that peterSO reported. Thanks all, thanks @peterSO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@peterSO mentioned that errors should always be checked in Go, I should had done that.